# Finding complete statistic from a single sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, complete-statistics

How do I find a complete statistic for the sample of size 1 of the following random variable:

$f(x; \theta) = \frac{2x}{\theta}I_{[0, \theta]}(x) + \frac{2(1-x)}{1-\theta}I_{[\theta, 1]}(x)$ ?

Intuitively, I feel like $X$ itself should be complete. From the definition of completeness, this amounts to proving:

If $\forall \theta\int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{2xg(x)}{\theta} dx +\int_{\theta}^{1}\frac{2g(x)(1-x)}{1-\theta}dx =0$ then $g(x) = 0$.

I tried differentiating the equation but got only $0 = 0$. Or maybe a complete statistic doesn't exist.

Comment: Hint: consider step functions $g$.

Comment: Are you hinting that there is a non zero step function g such that the sum of the integrals is zero for all theta?

Comment: @Xi'an Is it possible to show that a complete statistic doesn't exist?

Comment: @Xi'an For a sample of size 1, if X itself isn't complete, surely there isn't a complete statistic at all?